# How do I batch background jobs so I don't run out of memory on redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I'm sending about 3-million simple jobs to redis (saving a random string to the database as a unique ID).

```
  def self.update_public_ids
    Episode.where(public_id: nil).find_each{|e| UpdatePublicIds.perform_later(e.id)}
  end

def perform(episode_id)
  episode = Episode.find(episode_id)
  episode.set_public_id
end

def set_public_id
  code = generate_code
  self.public_id = code
  self.save
end
```

Every time it gets around 90K jobs queued I get this error:

```
Redis::CommandError: EXECABORT Transaction discarded because of previous errors.
```

Other SO answers have said this is caused by running out of memory on redis.  What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Increase RAM for your redis. Batching won't help here [too much]. If there's not enough RAM to store data - there's not enough RAM to store data.

Comment: Batching as in if 90,000+ tasks in redis cause it to crash, then just do 85000 at a time.  There are no callbacks to tell if the queue is clear?